# Find git repository on macOS

Tags: bash, shell, github, terminal, repository

I would like to find the location of a Git repository I made on my mac. Is there a way to find, for exemple, `albatrocity/git-version-control.markdown` on macOS using the Terminal? I installed everything with default parameters. I guess it must be in the `User` directory but I don't find anything related to GitHub there.

When I find it, I would like to completely remove it to maker a "proper" install.

EDIT: `sudo find / -name "parsing.py" -print`
I used a file that I know the folder contained when Terminal showed me nothing with `sudo find / -wholename "*albatrocity/git-version-control.markdown"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `find`'s `-wholename` option to find a file based on its name and folder:

```
find <directory> -wholename "*albatrocity/git-version-control.markdown"
```

Example, if you want to search in the `/Users/` directory:

```
find /Users/ -wholename "*albatrocity/git-version-control.markdown"
```

Comment: It didn't find anything at all

sudo find / -wholename "*albatrocity/git-version-control.markdown"
Password:
find: /dev/fd/3: Not a directory
find: /dev/fd/4: Not a directory

That's all I got.

Comment: That means the file `*albatrocity/git-version-control.markdown` you're looking for doesn't exist. Are you sure about its name and folder?

Comment: I'm only sure about the repo. I didn't chose anything when I installed it so maybe there isn't any folder. Is it possible? Is it possible to use this command or a command like this one to find a file that I'm sure must be in the directory where the repo is located?

EDIT: Found in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages
The file didn't had repo's name

Comment: `sudo find / -name "parsing.py" -print`
I looked for a file contained in the repo when it didn't find me anything the good way.
You were the closest one so you'll get your vote :)

Answer (score -1):

If you have locate on mac, and a regularly running updatedb, locate might be much faster:

```
locate albatrocity | grep git-version-control.markdown
```

It uses a hashtable to fast access filenames, but can be out of date, if the database isn't updated regularly or the file is too young (typically less than one day old).

If this is without success, then I would go for a full search with find, but maybe restrict it to a possible, narrowed path.

Comment: The complete command, even with sudo, didn't find anything. How is it possible?
It's still building the "locate".

Comment: If you accessed the file without sudo, you will find it without sudo. Maybe it isn't there. Maybe your updatedb is builded the first time, because it was never used before. Once builded, it gives results immediately, except from the youngest files which haven't been indexed yet, but often you know, whether you search for something new or old. The update daemon usually runs once a day but is configurable, and sometimes it is set to a fix time - which might always be, when the PC is off. There are tools for that problem too, but I don't know macOS installations. But the underlying BSD told me...

Comment: I often used "sudo" since it didn't work without it.

Comment: Well - you pay the price. Do, whatever you want, but then don't blame the system. Learning how to solve problems the right way pays off in the long run.

Comment: I didn't really had the choice since on GH the owner didn't explain another way to install than `pip-install`.